# What technology to choose for creating reusable component for Eclipse RCP and Java web application?

Tags: java, architecture, web-applications, frameworks, eclipse-rcp

We have two applications which solve different business tasks. One is based on Eclipse RCP. Another is web application based on Java server technologies.

Currently we need to develop one common component. It is for scheduling events. One group of users use Eclipse RCP application and will create and plan some events. Another group of users access web application and will view these scheduled events.

It is rather obvious, that it would be great if we can create one reusable component and integrate it with Eclipse ECP and Java web app.

The problem is what framework, technology, architecture to choose to solve this task.

- The component should be developed once and be reusable.
- It should have similar GUI in Eclipse RCP and in Java web app.
- The component integrated with Eclipse RCP should support offline work. So users should be able to schedule events without having Internet connection and somehow upload/merge their local version with online in web app later.

Do you have any ideas, recommendations?

If you need some additional information about the task and its requirements, feel free to ask, I will edit this question to have as full and clear description as possible here.

Answer (score 1):

The only technology I know of which approaches what you are looking for would be:

**[Eclipse RAP](https://web.archive.org/web/20100414041155/http://www.eclipse.org:80/rap/introduction.php)**

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/images/about/architecture.png))</sub>

> RAP is very similar to Eclipse RCP, but it has its own implementation of the SWT API (called RWT) which renders the widgets remotely on a web browser. The RAP application runs on a servlet container and clients can access the application with standard web browsers.

The idea is that a autonomous RCP application and its equivalent online RAP one will share almost all their code, except from web-specific bits.